# Handling FragmentTransaction - addToBackStack()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmenttransaction

I am working on an app which has activity and fragment structure shown below:

[image]

I couldn't implement the `FragmentTransaction`in such a way that when I press the back button in my phone it can go back to the previous fragments. So, the series begins in `SubFragment1` and ends in SecondActivity:
`SubFragment1`->`SubFragment2`->`SubFragment3`->`SecondActivity`
I am handling `FramgnetTransaction` stuff inside `FragmentB`:

```
//This part is inside onCreateView of FragmentB
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, SubFragment1(), FRAGMENT_SUB1);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("first");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

public void goToSubFragment2(){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, SubFragment2(), FRAGMENT_SUB2);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("second");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

public void goToSubFragment3(){
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, SubFragment3(), FRAGMENT_SUB3);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("three");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

When I want to go to the next `SubFragment` inside any `SubFragment`, I just use:

```
   ((FragmentB) this.getParentFragment()).goToSubFragment2();
```

And finally, in `SubFragment3`, I use the code below to go to `SecondActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

So, what happens when I press back button... If I am in one of the `SubFragments`, it closes the app. If I'm already in `SecondActivity` and press back button, the app crashes and in `LogCat` it says

```
Unable to resume activity {com.app_name.MainActivity1}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already executed.
```

In conclusion, my question is: Am I doing something wrong? Is it considered as wrong to handle `FragmentTransaction` stuff inside Fragment? If so, what is the correct way? Correct way to add actions to BackStack.
Why does back button not working properly?